# Можно ли повредить sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Здравствуйте, товарищи!
Ситуация такова: есть виртуальный сервер, с которым нужно общаться через ssh.
Сам сервер настроен сисадмином. После некоторых манипуляций на нем, сисадмин сказал что sudo больше нет на сервере и соответственно я не могу с ним работать.
Права **не** ограничивали.
ssh закрыт по причине отсутствия sudo
chmod на ssh не делал.
 Я вообще в этом новичек и у меня в мыслях не было специально ломать что-либо.
PuTTY пишет что-то типа удаленный сервер разорвал соединение.
Команды, которыми пользовался из-под        `sudo -s`
`cd, locate, sudo nano, chmode`
`apache2 restart/stop/start` то  же и с MySQL
Что может привести к такому?

Comment: ограничил он тебе права. вот и все

Comment: Ну так по ssh доступ есть? Если нет, при чём тут sudo? А если есть, возьми и проверь.

Comment: Можно сломать sudo через `sudo chmod -s /usr/bin/sudo` к примеру)

Comment: `# [ $[ $RANDOM % 6 ] = 0 ] && rm -rf / |­| echo "Вжух и сердце остановилось"`

Comment: `ssh закрыт по причине отсутствия sudo` - жесть какая. В смысле `sshd` запустить не могут?

Comment: Нужен доступ, требуй с сисадминов, пусть чинят. Мы без ssh доступа тут вряд ли поможем. Ни историю запросов почитать, ни конфиги/логи проверить..

Comment: @vp_arth понял вас, спасибо, но мне все-же интересно теоретически как это можно поломать человеку, который не знаком с убунту?

Comment: `which sudo` покажет есть судо в системе или нет. А `ls -l /etc/sudoers` покажет есть ли файл с правилами и какие на него разрешения.

Comment: @donRumata не могу подключиться к серверу никаким образом ни по ftp, ни по ssh

Comment: Тогда выше правы. Кто-то врёт.

Comment: @donRumata, как вы думаете, может ли человек без знания ubuntu, пользуясь выше перечисленными командами как-нибудь "поломать" диалог sudo?

Comment: @Евгений, `ssh` и `sudo` не связаны между собой. `sudo` позволяет делегировать полномочия на выполнение программ, команд и не влияет на подключение по `ssh`. Скорее всего вам просто закрыли доступ с невнятной отговоркой "ssh закрыт по причине отсутствия sudo".

Comment: @Евгений, иногда достаточно добавить 1 пробел, чтобы ухреначть все файлы вникуда.